# enabling developer mode in xiaomi redmi hm 1s

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, usb-debugging, xiaomi, developer-options

To enable the hidden Developer Options, I followed the following steps below :

1. On your Redmi phone, find and launch the Settings app.
2. Tap General settings.
3. Tap About phone.
4. Tap Android version for 7 times.
5. Once you reached the 7th times, it displays "K" after pressing K for some time it displays a screen showing in red color showing Android written at center and version written at bottom Android 4.4.4.
6. After pressing for some time it displays this screen with some animated gifs:

[image: Screenshot]

But as prescribed by Xiaomi offical documents step 5 and 6 doesn't come up 
instead it should be this

6. display a message "**You have enabled developer option**" on your device.Now you have successfully enabled Developer option tab.
7. Now you need to go back to main settings and then launch ***Additional*** ***Settings***.From their tap in ***developer options*** and enable it.and After that enable USB debugging .

But after the animated image display nothing happens as described .Even the option for Developer Option doesn't not show up....

So how to enable developer mode on this phone please help.??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Step 4 is probably wrong. That should read "build version". If you have a separate entry for "build", try that (and report back, please ;)

Comment: @Izzy I got it need to tap on MIUI version..instead of android version..

Comment: Great, congrats! May I suggest you make that an answer and accept it (ticking the green check-mark next to it), so other MIUI users can identify the solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Well ,I got it just ..need to Tap on **MIUI** **version** instead of Android version..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of android version you need to tap build version. I've noticed the same mistake in another guide but I can't seem to find it right now(may have been removed or fixed)